How to do fullRow edit with readyOnlyEdit in AG Grid?
When using both editType='fullRow' and readOnlyEdit in AG Grid (React), onRowValueChanged() doesn't get called after editing a row, and onRowEditingStopped() never contains the submitted data. How do I respond to a full-row edit request when using readOnlyEdit?

you can customize columns definition like this
const columnDefs = [
    {
        headerName: "Name",
        field: "name",
        editable: true, // This cell is always editable
    },
    {
        headerName: "Age",
        field: "age",
        editable: (params) => {
            // Make the cell editable only if a certain condition is met
            return params.data.age > 18;
        }
    },
    {
        headerName: "Country",
        field: "country",
        editable: false // This cell is read-only
    }
];

const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    singleClickEdit: true,
    editType: 'fullRow',
    onGridReady: (params) => {
        params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    },
    // other grid options
};

final note you can customize read-only column like this
{
    headerName: "Country",
    field: "country",
    editable: false, --> read only 
    cellClassRules: {
        'read-only-cell': 'data === true' // Apply CSS class based on condition
    }
}

